# Apparently random memory exhausted error

Tags: php, symfony, memcached, varnish, http-status-code-503

I'm having a weird issue that I'm having trouble to debug.
I have an application coded over Symfony2 distributed in three webservers behind a load balancer. There's an instance of Varnish on each one of the webservers.

At random times some of the webservers -one or two, rarely all of them- respond with a 503 error at the homepage for about 10 minutes or so and then everything goes back to normal.

The error is caused by a PHP Allowed memory size exhausted fatal error. But what I fail to understand is why the same app, with the same code, connecting to the same DB, etc. fails from one moment to another and then goes back to normal once again. And even the same app on different servers with the same hardware and software behave differently simultaneously.

My first guess was that the Varnish cache expired on the failing servers while the ones behaving normally still had a fresh copy cached with no errors. But if I manually flush the cache on all of the servers, the servers which had no errors respond with a 200 OK and the cache is regenerated successfully while the others keep failing.

And just to get even more weird... I realized that the same URL failing with some random query arguments responds correctly with some others. I mean arguments that do nothing in the code.

I'm running out of ideas on how debug this problem. Any clue would be truly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:
I'm also using Memcached to cache Doctrine queries and results. The Memory exhausted error is triggered when Doctrine attempts to store something in Memcached. The first guess would be to think that is trying to store a very large result but it still doesn't explain why it fails on one webserver while there's no problem on the others and all of them are processing the same queries from the same DB.

Comment: If I had to guess, [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) fills up and panics.

Comment: @castis Wow I forgot to mention that I'm using an opcode cache and I had no idea that it could cause a memory exhausted error on PHP. I'm definitely going to look into that! I'll let you know if that solves the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @castis actually I'm using Opcache - not APC. I tried resetting Opcache while the error was occurring but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you have some badly behaving PHP scripts and/or too high max allowed memory for PHP. Memory_limit * max processes with some 15mb per process to spare should never be higher than memory available. If you need more memory for some requests you should set up an extra pool with fewer max procs.

Also take into account that varnish can take up a rather big chunk of memory. Limit the cache size AND max concurrent connections. Each connection uses memory but the ammount is highly dependant on your VCL and size of the request (including headers).

It might get easier to handle and for sure gives better cache efficiency, if you place varnish at the load balancer layer.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but as I understand, the "Allowed memory size exhausted" error has nothing to do with max processes or total memory available. If that was the issue I think the error would be "Out of memory" instead.